# How to access the url in thymeleaf`

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-thymeleaf

I am working on an ecommerce website and I want to conditionally display a div in my layout only if the url does not match /auth/login.

```
    <div sec:authorize="isAnonymous()" th:if="${!/auth/login}">
        <a th:href="@{/auth/login}">Login</a>
        <a th:href="@{/auth/register}">Register</a>
    </div>
```

I read the documentation, but all I can find is the info on the params object. I also saw some stuff on google about the #httpservlet object, however I do believe that is depreciated do to the fact that I am not getting auto completion in intellij.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this way:

```
<div sec:authorize="isAnonymous()" th:if="${#httpServletRequest.requestURI != '/auth/login'}">
    <a th:href="@{/auth/login}">Login</a>
    <a th:href="@{/auth/register}">Register</a>
</div>.
```

Useful link about that implementation : https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#appendix-a-expression-basic-objects